# only use api/array data that meets a specific criteria

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I have some api data, that is structured as follows

```
information
   random number
      price
      amount
      total
   random number
      price
      amount
      total
```

data i use atm to grab the lowest price:

```
$all_prices = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['price'];
}, $info_array['information']);
$price = min($all_prices);
```

Now i want 3 things with this data.

1. grab the lowest price (i was able to do this, see code above)
2. Grab the corresponding amount, for the row that has the lowest price (no idea if this is possible, or how to do this)
3. if 2 is not possible, place a filter, saying something like: grab the lowest price, but only if amount is > 50?

any help is greatly appreciated

edit:
if 2 or more things have the same "lowest price"  for amounts:
combining them, picking 1 of the 2, picking the first, or the highest amount would al be fine for this case.
The chance this happens is very small with this data. so small that i am fine with not coding anything in for that situation because this will not cause issues for the result (if it works 99% of the time, it is good enough)

Comment: Do note that there can be more than one record with a minimum price (two items can have the same price which matches the minimum), so there can be different values for amount for each one that matches the minimum price. (Unless this is a ficticious example/experiment where prices are forced to be unique)

Comment: combining them, picking 1 of the 2, picking the first, or the highest amount would al be fine for this case. The chance this happens is very small with this data. so small that i am fine with not coding anything in for that situation because this will not cause issues for the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do by iterating an array and grabbing an item that satisfies your conditions. Something like that.

```
<?php

$info_array = [
    'information' => [
        [
            'price'  => 100,
            'amount' => 300,
            'total'  => 300,
        ],
        [
            'price'  => 40,
            'amount' => 150,
            'total'  => 150,
        ],
        [
            'price'  => 70,
            'amount' => 140,
            'total'  => 140,
        ],
    ],
];

$lowestPriceItem              = null;
$lowestPriceMoreThanFiftyItem = null;

foreach ($info_array['information'] as $item) {
    if (!$lowestPriceItem || $item['price'] < $lowestPriceItem['price']) {
        $lowestPriceItem = $item;
    }

    if (!$lowestPriceMoreThanFiftyItem
        || ($item['price'] > 50 && $item['price'] < $lowestPriceMoreThanFiftyItem['price'])
    ) {
        $lowestPriceMoreThanFiftyItem = $item;
    }
}

var_dump(
    $lowestPriceItem['price'] ?? null,
    $lowestPriceItem['amount'] ?? null
); // the lowest price and the corresponding amount

var_dump(
    $lowestPriceMoreThanFiftyItem['price'] ?? null,
    $lowestPriceMoreThanFiftyItem['amount'] ?? null
); // the lowest price > 50 and the corresponding amount
```

Comment: thank you, i got the first part to work with this. having a look at the amount > 50 part now. doesnt work yet, but will update this if get that to work aswell :)

Comment: got that part to work aswel, made it: (!$lowestPriceMoreThanFiftyItem && $item['amount'] > 50|| ($item['amount'] > 50 && $item['price'] < $lowestPriceMoreThanFiftyItem['price'])